# Apache Nutch failed to load hadoop naive library

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, solr, nutch

I am new in Apache nutch, so i followed Apache nutch tutorial from the Apache wiki,
 environment is:
**Windows 10

Jdk 1.8

Cygin 2.9.0

Apache Nutch 1.14

Solr 6.6.2

winutils - hadoop-2.8.1**
i already set up JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME
when i run crawl command in Cygin
./crawl -s urls mycrawdir 3 
the below error appeared
Injecting seed URLs
/home/apache-nutch-1.14/bin/nutch inject mycrawdir/crawldb urls
Injector: starting at 2018-01-19 20:55:48
Injector: crawlDb: mycrawdir/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <br>org.apache.hadoop.io.                                                                                                                nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:6                                                                                                                09)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskCheck                                                                                                                er.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:17                                                                                                                4)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChange                                                                                                                d(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPa                                                                                                                thForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirA                                                                                                                llocator.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirA                                                                                                                llocator.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirA                                                                                                                llocator.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDist                                                                                                                ributedCacheManager.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.jav                                                                                                                a:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java                                                                                                                :731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitt                                                                                                                er.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma                                                                                                                tion.java:1746)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:417)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:528)
Error running:
  /home/apache-nutch-1.14/bin/nutch inject mycrawdir/crawldb urls
Failed with exit value 1.
```